# Postfix intercept emails with apache server

Tags: smtp, domain

I have a server(using postfix) to relay emails to a smtp server. I am tasked with separating the emails by the domain(2 to be exact) to send to 2 separate smtp servers. The idea was to use transport as this suggestion: [Postfix to relay mails to other SMTP for particular domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/257637/postfix-to-relay-mails-to-other-smtp-for-particular-domain).

For example I have an email send to the address test@domain1.com which points to the existing smtp server(setup using relay_host). Now I want to make it so if I have email sending to test@**domain2.com**, this will send to a different smtp server(spoofed apache server to read incoming messages).I have a generally idea how the apache part will work but please let me know if there some stuff regarding postfix to enable the forwarding of the second smtp server correctly, such as authentication issues.

Much thanks.

Comment: You want to forward messages via SMTP to an HTTP server?

Comment: Yes, if the domain is the specified server the message should be forward to an http server.

Comment: SMTP and HTTP are completely separate protocols that have little to no commonality. This isn't going to happen.

Comment: In terms of adding transport_maps, is this the correct way?