# Configure Postfix external relay for UCEPROTECTL3 rejection

Tags: postfix, smtp, spam

Is it possible to configure MTA Postfix server to bypass UCEPROTECTL3 rejection ?
Example when my server connect to recipient server then I get information:
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 5.7.1 You are not allowed to connect.

Ok I know to I can set up relay postfix on external ( unbanned ) server. Ok then I will skip blacklist. But then all my emails will be sending by another relay server not selectively.
Is it possible to selectively change the relay server taking into account rejections caused by blacklist ?
Example when my server get 554 error then it use another relay server which is clean.

My server is free from spam but UCEPROTECTL3 block all OVH IP :(

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/257637/postfix-to-relay-mails-to-other-smtp-for-particular-domain

Comment: Why complicate things, why not send *all* outgoing mail using an IP managed by a provider compliant with the rules of the list maintainers you care about?

Comment: Is it possible to set IP instead of domain recipient in transport_maps ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to configure a server to send something that the receiving server does not want to receive.

If the receiving server is using a blacklist that your IP address or domain are listed on, then all you can do is petition the blacklist manager to remove your IP address or domain from their list or migrate to a different IP address or domain.

Otherwise you will need to use some alternative sending method, such as a relay.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using:

- using transport_maps:
  main.cf file: transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport_maps

transport_maps file:

```
# recipient domains that have rejected the main MX
domain1.com   relay[your-spare.smtp.com]:25
domain2.com   relay[your-spare.smtp.com]:25
```

- using smtp_fallback_relay:

main.cf file:

```
smtp_fallback_relay: [your-spare.smtp.com]:25
```